# Java Help For calculating %10 increase

Tags: java

I am still a beginner in java but I have this code below I am nearly done writing but I am having difficulty in trying to figure out how to calculate the %10. Also for some reason, it would only take the original 20000.00 and 30000.00 and display that instead of the new %10 increased salary. How exactly to do this? Any help or insight is appreciated, thank you,

```
public class Employee 
{
  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;
  private double MonthlySalary;

  public Employee (String FirstName, String LastName, double MonthlySalary)
  {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
    this.LastName = LastName;
    this.MonthlySalary = MonthlySalary;
  }



  public void setFirstName (String firstName)
  {
    this.FirstName = FirstName;
  }

  public String getFirstName ()
  {
    return FirstName;
  }

  public void setLastName (String last)
  {
    this.LastName = LastName;
  }

  public String getLastName ()
  {
    return LastName;
  }

  public void setMonthlySalary (double salary)
  {
    if ( MonthlySalary < 0 )
       this.MonthlySalary = 0;
    else 
       this.MonthlySalary = MonthlySalary;
  }

  public double getMonthlySalary ()
  {
    return MonthlySalary;
  }
}

public class EmployeeTest 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Employee employee1 = new Employee ( " Bruce ", " Wayne ", 30000.00 );
        Employee employee2 = new Employee ( " Clark ", " Kent ", 20000.00);

        System.out.println( "Employee1:   " + employee1.getFirstName() + employee1.getLastName()  );//Displays employee1 name
        System.out.println( "Initial Salary: $ " + employee1.getMonthlySalary ()  );//Displays initial yearly salary

        System.out.println( "Employee2:  " + employee2.getFirstName () + employee2.getLastName()  );//Displays employee2 name
        System.out.println( "Initial Salary: $ " + employee2.getMonthlySalary ()  );//Displays initial yearly salary    

        System.out.println( "\n\t\t\t********Salary After 10% Raise********\n\t\t\t");//Banner to separate initial salary from 10% raised salary

        System.out.println( "Employee1:  " + employee1.getFirstName() +employee1.getLastName()  );//Displays employee1 name
        System.out.println( "Salary After 10% Raise:  " + employee1.getMonthlySalary()  );//Displays yearly salary after the 10% increase

        System.out.println( "Employee2:  " + employee2.getFirstName() +employee2.getLastName()  );//Displays employee2 name
        System.out.println( "Salary After 10% Raise:  " +  employee2.getMonthlySalary() );//Displays yearly salary after the 10% increase
    }
}
```

Comment: Just multiply the salary by 1.1

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate 10% ?  That's a maths question, not java

Comment: Where are you attempting to increase the salary by 10%?

Comment: It's required for my code before Is submit it. As for the maths portion I get that 1.1 would be the way to go about doing it now but for some reason the new increased salary isnt whats displayed after I compile run.

Comment: And why are you expecting it to show the new increased salary?

Answer (score 1):

Before printing the increased salary you should set the the new value. 
To do this, you have to modify your setMonthlySalary method like this:

```
public void setMonthlySalary (double salary) {
    if ( salary < 0 )
       this.MonthlySalary = 0;
    else 
       this.MonthlySalary = salary;
  }
```

and do

```
employee1.setMonthlySalary(employee1.getMonthlySalary() * 1.1L);
employee2.setMonthlySalary(employee2.getMonthlySalary() * 1.1L);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining monthlySalary after 10% raise -  create a value for monthlySalaryAfter10 and multiply monthlySalary by 1.1

Answer (score -1):

say you have a value 5 and you want to increase it by 10% this means you should know how much is 10% from your value which is .5 and then you add the value and the value of 10% to your increased value
this process is similar to multiplying your value to 110%
so first process :
5 * .1 = .5
5 + .5  = 5.5

and this takes so much steps
this is the second process where you get the value of 110% of it

5 * 110/100 = 5 * 1.1 = 5.5